# Force throw defense

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In various scenes, a Jedi or a Sith moves big & heavy objects (like in the Yoda vs Dooku duel at the end of *Attack of the Clones*) and throws it to opponent. Isn't the other way easier - throwing the opponent at the object? Does a Force-user hold himself/herself in place through the Force to counter that?

Similarly, does Yoda walk using the Force? He was so old that he could hardly walk but in battle he performed well against everyone (rolling, flipping, slashing very fast, jumping through walls).

Comment: I'm not aware of canon proof, but: (1) usually, Jedi would throw lighter things than a human body; (2) throwing a thing allows the opponent being hit to be thrown further (via momentum conservation) and thus inflict secondary damage, or disorient more - as opposed to being stopped in place; (3) the Force clearly allowed people performing beyond "normal" abilities, so Yoda's fight movements are likely a part of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL; DR:** Yes, it is possible to throw a force-sensitive opponent, however, it can be countered by the opposing duelist.

According to the Wookieepedia page on [Telekinesis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Telekinesis),

> *Force Pull*: A telekinetic ability using the Force that could cause a material body to draw close to the user. The greater the user's aptitude with this, the heavier the object that could be pulled or the more wide arc or radius of the Force "wave". It could be used to pull weapons from enemies, or, **at higher levels of skill, the enemies themselves to be brought closer to a Jedi's lightsaber range.** (emphasis mine)

As far as I can remember, we never see this in the films, but we do see Force Push in the Yoda vs Sidious battle, when Yoda pushes Sidious out of his chair.

> *Force Push*: At more powerful levels, Force Push was the ability to create a telekinetic impulse via the Force, launching a concussive burst of pressurized air-not unlike the blast of an archaic 'pipe bomb'-that would impact a target with enough force to knock it over, launch it into the air, or even (particularly in the case of fragile materials such as ceramics) shatter it into pieces.
>
> This power was an effective tool for keeping enemies at a distance. A well-aimed push could send a target crashing into a nearby wall or other obstruction, resulting in bludgeoning damage and possible disorientation or blackout. **A Force push could also cause direct damage, by striking an enemy in the form of a telekinetic fist which had the power of a pile driver. This could injure or even kill enemies through the sheer power of the kinetic blast alone, rather than the damage caused by the collision of the target with a larger obstruction.** (emphasis mine)

However, it should be noted that in the film, Sidious was clearly surprised by Yoda's attack and it would not always work on a trained Force-User.

> A trained Force user could resist Force Push, presumably by generating an opposing pressure surge whose wavefront canceled out their opponent's attack. The opponent usually responded by ramping up the pressure to compensate for the increased resistance. From here it became a telekinetic arm-wrestling match, with a seemingly motionless facade belying each combatant's desperate struggle to overpower the other...A textbook example was provided by Darth Vader and Obi-Wan Kenobi when their duel progressed into the control room of the mining platform on Mustafar. The two had simultaneously used the ability while resisting each other's at the same time. Like magnets of the same pole, the combined force eventually hurled them violently to opposite sides of the room.

Additionally, Count Dooku used a form of Telekinesis against Obi-Wan in the duel immediately preceeding his death:

[image: Dooku Force-chokes and levitates Obi-Wan before force throwing him across the room]

In reference to your question about Yoda, his [Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda#Personality_and_traits) says:

> Yoda walked with the aid of a cane later in life, although he was capable of throwing it aside and moving nimbly while using the Force.
>
> ...
>
> Much of his lightsaber combat style relied on jumps and acrobatics, many of which were aided by the Force and augmented by his mastery of Force Valour.

Comment: During Anakin and Obi-Wan's duel in "Revenge of the Sith," they both Force Push each other at the same time, throwing both across the room after a couple seconds of struggle. And there are various instances of a force push on a force user in Star Wars: The Clone Wars. (The newer one) Ashoka pushes Ventress away from Luminari Undali (sorry if I misspelled) in one of the episodes from several years ago. I can't remember which one. It was the one where they were delivering Nute Gunray and were stopped by Ventress and a senate commando.

Comment: @jacen.garriss - Thanks. I did note the Anakin/Obi-Wan duel, but as I haven't seen the Clone Wars, I wasn't aware of those.

Comment: "Yoda walked with the aid of a cane later in life, although he was capable of throwing it aside and moving nimbly while using the Force." - this is simply Wikia users writing up what they see in the movie, NOT some canon exlpanation. Wookiepedia isn't canon, just user generated content, unless cited.