# Jedi/Sith using force in combat with other Jedi/Sith?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, sith

Before reading this, bear in mind my knowledge of the Star Wars universe is solely from the films, so apologies if I say things that are incorrect.

So this has been bugging me lately -- Could Jedi/Sith use the force on other Jedi/Sith during lightsaber fights? If so, why don't they? I'm not talking full-out breaking their opponent's necks or throwing them across the room, but more like just pushing them off balance using minimal force push/pulling.

From other topics I've read, it seems the popular opinion is that force-users can block the use of the force on them by other force-users, and thus it is incredibly hard and requires great concentration in order to apply major force-manipulation to another force user (ie. breaking a neck). This leads me to believe that BOTH sides must be concentrating on use of the force to attack/defend.

I'm imagining this kind of scenario, but a mental battle:

[image]

Now, given that during a lightsaber battle the individuals involved are most likely concentrating more on the fight and not on protecting themselves from the force, theoretically could a force-master -- during a fight with someone less accomplished with the force -- use periodic pushes and pulls to knock their opponent off balance?

Some might say they would have no reason to, but, as someone who has trained in martial arts, if I was trying to sword-fight (for lack of a better verb) someone, and the whole time I was being pushed around, I would lose pretty damn quick.

Another argument I've seen is that Jedi don't like to use the force in battles because it brings them closer to the dark side, which is acceptable, but why not Sith then?

**Edit**: The proposed duplicate seems to be asking more about a heavily concentrated push of the entire Jedis' bodies into the chasm, I'm suggesting more of a nudge off balance which I believe would require much less focus.

Comment: Great question, and welcome to the site!  As it happens, a very similar question has already been asked here.

Comment: Only one vote has been cast for closing the question as a duplicate, so you don't have to worry about it just yet.  If I was wrong to vote to close it, no one else will vote to close, the question will remain open.

Comment: This answer to a different question might explain why Jedi and Sith don't use force techniques in a heated battle - doing so would give their enemy an advantage, because their concentration would be diverted from the task at hand. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/89312/44025

Comment: Another possible duplicate:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40932/44025

Comment: And another one:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75982/why-didn-t-either-darth-vader-or-obi-wan-use-the-force-in-their-final-battle

Comment: A much more brutal version of your idea:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/why-dont-jedi-or-sith-use-the-force-to-snap-their-foes-necks?rq=1

Comment: They can. They don't, because it would make the sword fights look less impressive. The actors learn sword fighting from humans, not jedi. So, the sword fights look like regular movie-style sword fights instead of how they could potentially look.