# Why don't Jedi simply fight using the Force instead of the more cumbersome lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

By using the Force, they can control the minds of their opponents and make them commit suicide. Fighting with lightsabers is more cumbersome in comparison, not to mention using blasters is more efficient.

Comment: see also: [When multiple Jedi attack one target, why do they all attack physically?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85710/5184), [Could several Jedi peacefully overpower one Sith opponent through nonviolent Force techniques?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89320/5184), [Force throw defense](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40926/5184), [Why didn' t either Darth Vader or Obi-Wan use the force in their final battle?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75982/5184)

Comment: with your edits, this is now a dupe of [Could several Jedi peacefully overpower one Sith opponent through nonviolent Force techniques?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89320/5184).

Comment: You're right. It's a duplicate.